# Rails, Node.js cross-server authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, mongodb, node.js, devise

So I'm making a rails app that also utilizes node.js for realtime features. What is the best way to authenticate the users on the node app, if they were created with devise on rails? I've been thinking about saving the session id in the db, and then validating with that, or maybe displaying the user id in the page and then sending that to the node app when they connect. Or maybe something else entirely would be best. I'm using mongoose for my node orm and mongoid for ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the session id in your database is a valid approach, I do that in my own applications.

Comment: Do you know of an easy way to get the session id in node? Is it encrypted at all from rails?

Comment: @user741072, if both apps (rails and node) are hosted on the same domain, the session cookie created by one app will be transmitted by the browse to the other application.  All you need to know is the name of the cookie.

Comment: rails cookies are encrypted. if you don't want to store session ID in the DB, might be a good idea to use decrypt in the same way rails does. need to put the cookie key in nodejs code as well. I'm thinking to follow this way for this, I also have a rails with some node code